# What is a "jerry-built area" in the 1937 HOLC maps?

Tags: united-states, great-depression

Established as part of the New Deal, the [Home Owners' Loan Corporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_Owners%27_Loan_Corporation) offered mortgage loans to expand home buying. In the process it made a detailed grading of neighborhoods into categories A (green) to D (red), with important long-term consequences on racial discrimination.

I am interested in the description of the C (yellow) category:

> The Third grade or C areas are characterized by age, obsolescence, [...]. "Jerry" built areas are included as well as neighborhoods lacking homogeneity.

Source: [the 1937 map for Hartford, CT](http://magic.lib.uconn.edu/magic_2/vector/37840/primary_source/hdimg_37840_064_1937_holc_national_archives_trinity.pdf), but similar descriptions can be found [elsewhere](http://salt.umd.edu/T-RACES/colormap.html).

My questions are: what is/was a "Jerry" built area? Were they a direct consequence of the Great Depression? And why would they automatically get graded C?

Comment: OED has: "*Badly or hastily built with materials of poor quality*". Origin: "*Mid 19th century: origin unknown; sometimes said to be from the name of a firm of builders in Liverpool, or to allude to the walls of Jericho, which fell down at the sound of Joshua’s trumpets (Josh. 6:20)*".  Personally, I think I'd go with the "origin unknown" bit, and take the rest with a large spoonful of salt.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize this was a common expression (and it didn't come up in a generic search). This is an off-topic question, feel free to close or downvote!

Comment: you might be more familiar with usage in the term "jerry rigged" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jury_rigging#:~:text=Jury%20rigging%20(also%20called%20%22jerry,sail%20powered%20to%20begin%20with.